# Есть ли бесплатные переводчики с API?

Tags: перевод, поиск-api

Нужно перевести несколько миллионов страниц текста. Переводчики от Google и Яндекса слишком дорогие (~$20 за 1 000 000 символов). Есть ли бесплатные аналоги переводчиков с API?

Comment: Попробуйте что-то такое https://github.com/LibreTranslate/LibreTranslate

Answer (score 1):

Совсем бесплатные либо без API, либо со множеством ограничений.
Самый дешевый (для больших объемов текста) этот:
[Fast Translator](https://fasttranslator.herokuapp.com)